# How to use the gamma distribution to induce heteroskedasticity in the errors of a linear model

Tags: linear-model, heteroscedasticity, gamma-distribution

Suppose for $Y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$, $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^p$ and $\epsilon\in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have the linear model

\begin{equation}
Y=X\beta +\epsilon,\quad \epsilon\sim N(0,\Sigma)
\end{equation}
where for homoskedastic errors,
\begin{equation}
\Sigma=
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma^2 &0 &\cdots & 0\\
0 &\sigma^2 & \cdots& 0\\
\vdots &\vdots &\ddots & \vdots\\
0& 0&\cdots &\sigma^2
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Now suppose, we wish to induce heteroskedasticity at different rates to the errors, i.e., such that $\sigma_1\neq \sigma_2\neq\cdots\neq \sigma_n$. In [a supplementary document by Karl Rohe](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/15-EJS1029SUPP), they achieve this by generating the $\sigma_i$-s using Gamma distribution with equal scale and shape parameters. However, it is not immediately obvious to me how this rate is nominated to correspond to varying degrees of heteroskedasticty. Of course, evidently the shape=scale parameters are changed iteratively in their paper. However, how does one do this to generate models with errors exhibiting *no heteroskedasticity* all the way to *high heteroskedasticity*, as it has been done in their figure below?

[image]